# Mobile data is not turning off programmatically

Tags: android

I am using the following code repeatedly to toggle between the ON and OFF states in mobile data.

```
//Turning mobile data ON/OFF
boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
try {
    Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
    Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
    method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
    // get the setting for "mobile data"
    mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);
    method.setAccessible(false);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Some problem accessible private API
    // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if(mobileDataEnabled)
{
    try {
        System.out.println("Mobile data switching off");
        ConnectivityManager enableDataConn = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Class enableClass = Class.forName(enableDataConn.getClass().getName());
        java.lang.reflect.Field iConnectivityManagerField = enableClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(enableDataConn);
        Method method2 = enableClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        method2.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
        // get the setting for "mobile data"
        method2.invoke(enableDataConn, false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Mobile data cannot be enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} else {
    try {
        System.out.println("Mobile data switching on");
        ConnectivityManager enableDataConn = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Class enableClass = Class.forName(enableDataConn.getClass().getName());
        java.lang.reflect.Field iConnectivityManagerField = enableClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(enableDataConn);
        Method method2 = enableClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        method2.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
        // get the setting for "mobile data"
        method2.invoke(enableDataConn, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Mobile data cannot be enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above mentioned code is kept inside the onclick method of an onClicklistener method.

I have no problem turning **ON** the mobile data when it is OFF, but **it does not switch off when I try to toggle again**. Also I do not get any exception in this case.
It always goes into the **else** condition of the code.

Please let me know what changes I must make so that this works both ways.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
public boolean getMobileDataEnabled() throws Exception {
    ConnectivityManager mcm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Class ownerClass = mcm.getClass();
    Method method = ownerClass.getMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
    return (Boolean)method.invoke(mcm);
}

public void setMobileDataEnabled(boolean enabled) throws Exception {
    ConnectivityManager mcm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Class ownerClass = mcm.getClass();
    ownerClass.getMethod("setMobileDataEnabled",boolean.class).invoke(mcm, enabled);
}
```

In `OnClickListener()` add these code:

```
try {
    boolean isMobileDataEnable = getMobileDataEnabled();
    setMobileDataEnabled(!isMobileDataEnable);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I no longer have access to the facilities of the project I was working on.. so I cannot verify your answer. But I thank you for your help.